# Multi Dimentional Number of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to make a 2 dimentional array that contain numbers iterate from 1 to height^2.
the input is height and the output like this if the height is 5:

```
[ [ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ],
  [ 20, 19, 18, 17, 16 ],
  [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ],
  [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ]
```

I've already code it like here:

```
function snakeLadder(height) {

  for (var i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
    var output = [];
    for (var j = 1; j < height; j++) {
      output.push(i + j);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

and the output turns out to be like this :

```
[ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 3, 4 ]
```

can anyone pinpoint the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function snakeLadder(height) {
  var result = []
  for(var i = height-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = [];
    for(var j = 1; j <= height; j++) {
      // if it's odd rows, increase(push), otherwise decrease(unshift)
      if((height-i-1)%2 == 0)
        row.push(height*i + j);
      else
        row.unshift(height*i + j);
    }
    result.push(row);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(snakeLadder(5));
```

Comment: I've try the code and it works wonder for height 5. However,  I've found that if the height is 3, the output do not format correctly even though the array is ok. the output is like this :  [ [ 7, 8, 9 ], [ 6, 5, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ] where it should be 3 x 3 grid like height 5 output. any ideas?

Comment: @AdeKurniawan the output do not format correctly? could you explain more please?

Comment: i want it to be like chess board which is the output will be show like a grid. it's ok with height 5, but not with height 3. After the comma, the next array do not place on the next line but instead on the same line.
here is the picture for more detail. One is what it should be and the other is the current result.
https://pictr.com/image/01IphG
https://pictr.com/image/01I1xc

Comment: output format does not make any difference for computer. what is this format for? human?

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer array where you unshift the row.

Then you better loop from zero to less than `height` and take a multiplication with the height and an offset of one to get the right value.

```js
function snakeLadder(height) {
    var temp, result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        temp = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            temp.push(i * height + j + 1);
        }
        if (i & 1) {
            temp.reverse();
        }
        result.unshift(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(snakeLadder(5).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the result is not the same as in the question

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue with your code is your rows aren't being added to a final, result array. Secondarily, you'll need to reverse the odd rows to match your expected output.

Here's a succinct ES6 version which uses the `...` spread operator on `Array` constructors to create rows and columns, which are mapped to the two-dimensional result array. Parity is tested on row index `j` using the binary `& 1` to reverse rows where the least significant bit is set:

```js
const snakeLadder = (h, i=h*h) => 
  [...Array(h)].map((r, j) => {
    const row = [...Array(h)].map(c => i--)
    return j & 1 ? row : row.reverse();
  })
;

console.log(snakeLadder(5));
```

Comment: The output is different.

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      var output = [];
          if((i+2)%2 ==0){
                for (var j = 1; j <=height; j++) {
                          output.push( (i * height ) + j );
                }
          }
          else if( (i%2) ==1){
                 for (var j = height; j>0; j--) {
                           output.push( (i * height) + j );
                }
          }
     }
            return output;
    }
```

Comment: this is the output after I tried your code: 
[ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ]
[ 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 4, 3 ]

Comment: Fixed issues.Output shows correctly for me. Is it what you expected now?